# Is there a shortcut key for paging through method signatures in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to be able to cycle through the constructor/method signatures using a shortcut key, instead of having to click on the up and down arrows.  Is this possible?

[image: Screenshot of VS2019 with a line of code showing a constructor with 10 signatures]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to iterate through the list of overloads once your cursor is after the first parenthesis and the tooltip is shown (as per your screenshot).

Comment: Not working for vs 2022 community.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + SPACE is the shortcut for `Parameter Info`, but that only shows/hides the popup. It doesn't cycle through the list of overloads.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.8.4...

<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrows do it, but you need to dismiss the Intellicode/sense list that is displayed at the same time and has the focus, using <kbd>Esc</kbd>.